# Phalcon Save: Can I update only specified columns if update?

Tags: save, phalcon

I have a table with this columns:

```
param_id
val_value
val_flag
date_value
tmp_value
tmp_flag
```

And I have an array of elements, I always have param_id and date_value, but sometimes i have val columns and other times I have tmp columns.

I use `$data->save()` because sometimes I need to create a new register in db and other times I need to update the register with param_id and date_value.

The question is: Is there any way to do an insert/update but when is an update, only update tmp columns or val columns? I think a find First is my only option, but maybe there is another way.

Thank you.

[EDIT]

I'm trying with the whitelist but it does not work. Let me explain how the method works: I get a request to a web service, process the xml and generate an array of elements with the information collected, after processing these elements I have an array of elements of the class appropriate to save, but these may be new or existing and may contain tmp or val values, I have tried with this but I still change the values to null.

```
if ($medida->tipo == 'temporal'){
  $whiteList = array('val_value','val_flag');
}else if ($medida->tipo == 'validado'){
  $whiteList = array('tmp_value','tmp_flag');
}
$dato->save(null, $whitelist);
```

I do not have data of the post, I use null instead, I have also tried to use an array with the manual assignment of the data obtaining the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options that can help you:

**1)** Use 'whitelist' for the `save()` method.

```
$obj->save($this->request->getPost(), ['tmp_1', 'tmp_2']);
```

More info in [**the documentation**](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#creating-updating-records).

**2)** Use the 'Event Manager'.

The methods `beforeCreate()` and `beforeUpdate()` will be useful so you can decide which fields to use.

More info in **[the documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/odm.html#validation-events-and-events-manager)**.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you really want phalcon phql to update only columns which changed you need to enable dynamic update.

Comment: Add `$this->useDynamicUpdate(true);` to the `initialize` method in your model.

Comment: I did not have initialize method so I created it, now it does nothing, I have this:
`public function initialize(){
  $this->useDynamicUpdate(true);
  parent::initialize();
 }`
Is this correct?